# Error in excel formula when LEN(cell) > 255

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I just found out that when you're doing a COUNTIF() formula on a cell with more than 255 characters, it retun a #VALUE error.

Do you know how to deal with that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Excel documentation:

> The COUNTIF function returns incorrect results when you use it to match strings longer than 255 characters.
>
> To match strings longer than 255 characters, use the CONCATENATE
>   function or the concatenate operator &. For example,
>   =COUNTIF(A2:A5,"long string"&"another long string").

[COUNTIF Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately I have to do this to multiple values and it's impossible to use your tip. Thank you for your time.

Comment: What criteria do you need to use for your COUNTIF?

Comment: To replace the COUNTIF function, I can totally use a SUMPRODUCT. But I can't use sumproduct with COUNTIFS. See more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40039282/identify-names-with-same-id-and-same-age